# Why some values are missing in $_POST?

Tags: php, post

I have many

```
<input type="checkbox" name="course_id[]" value="xxx"/>
```

in my form. However `$_POST['course_id']` has only part of values submitted.

For example, I post `course_id[]=1&course_id[]=2&course_id[]=3&course_id[]=4` but `$_POST['course_id']` is `["1","2","3"].`

In the real situation more than 1000 course_ids are posted but only about 990 course_ids are in `$_POST['course_id']`.

I have captured the HTTP package by tshark and found all values of course_id[] are posted to PHP.

The PHP version is 5.5.9

Comment: you don't need tshark for this, use live http headers for firefox

Comment: @PedroLobito I captured the HTTP package on the server to ensure that all values were received by the server.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII echo json_encode($_POST['course_id'])

Comment: for the input type checkbox, browser is only transmitting checked values, so what you had described is correct - you have 990 checked checkboxes and 10 unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue you are running into is the `max_input_vars` is set to its default value, 1000. I think you are sending 10 other parameters and then your `990 course_ids` max the 1000 limit. Up that limit and you can send more than 1000 parameters.

You can read more on the manual's page, http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars.

From the manual:

```
Name            Default Changeable      Changelog
max_input_vars  1000    PHP_INI_PERDIR  Available since PHP 5.3.9.
```

> How many input variables may be accepted (limit is applied to $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal separately). Use of this directive mitigates the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash collisions. If there are more input variables than specified by this directive, an E_WARNING is issued, and further input variables are truncated from the request.

Keep the purpose of this setting in mind though:

> Use of this directive mitigates the possibility of denial of service attack.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP configuration, POST is limited to a certain size. According the number of course, maybe you reached that limit.
You can check this value `post_max_size`

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: I have increased the "post_max_size" to 8 times as large as the original, but the situation is still the same.

Comment: ok, do you expect to have unchecked value to come ? cause it will not be send. only checked value will be sent

Comment: The problem is PHP drops some checked values, which can be captured by tshark